# validation returns false on first input and true on next inputs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

This timepicker component is part from a form generator. I pass in some items and they will get processed to text inputs, number inputs, ... and so on.

Due to the fact you can't store validation functions to the database we store regex patterns to the database. For this example I only want to check if that field is not empty.

The form generates a timepicker component which is able to validate the input. Unfortunately the validation returns `false` for the first input. When changing the time a second time it returns `true`. Clearing the field will also return `true`.

I created a demo. The consuming component uses this code

```
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <TimeField
      v-for="maskItem in maskItems"
      :key="maskItem.fieldId"
      :value="maskItem.value"
      :rules="getValidation(maskItem)"
      @input="onMaskItemValueUpdated(maskItem.fieldId, ...arguments)"
    />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import TimeField from "./components/TimeField";

export default {
  components: {
    TimeField
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      maskItems: [
        {
          fieldId: 1,
          value: null,
          validation: [
            {
              pattern: new RegExp(".{1,}"),
              message: "This field is required"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getValidation: function(maskItem) {
      return maskItem.validation.map(rule => value =>
        (value && rule.pattern.test(value)) || rule.message
      );
    },
    onMaskItemValueUpdated: function(fieldId, newValue) {
      this.maskItems.find(
        fieldToUpdate => fieldToUpdate.fieldId === fieldId
      ).value = newValue;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The timepicker itself is able to format the time if it should display the time format for a specific locale. When formatting the date the textfield will pass in the formatted date to the validation. This is **wrong**. To handle this behaviour I created the `getValidationRules` function and pass in the correct value to the validation. However, it is using this code

```
<template>
  <v-menu :value="showMenu" max-width="290px">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-text-field
        :value="formattedTime"
        clearable
        v-on="on"
        :required="true"
        :rules="formatBasedRules"
        @input="selectValue"
      ></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-time-picker :value="value" @input="selectValue"/>
  </v-menu>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    },
    rules: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      showMenu: false,
      formatBasedRules: [true]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    formattedTime: function() {
      // ... !! format time here !! ...
      return this.value;
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.formatBasedRules = this.getValidationRules();
  },
  methods: {
    selectValue: function(newValue) {
      this.showMenu = false;
      this.$emit("input", newValue);
      this.formatBasedRules = this.getValidationRules();
    },
    getValidationRules: function() {
      for (const rule of this.rules) {
        const result = rule(this.value);

        if (typeof result === "string") {
          return [result];
        }
      }

      return [true];
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I created an example for reproduction

https://codesandbox.io/s/menu-picker-validation-eorep

Just select a time and you will receive an error message. Select another time and the validation will return `true`. Clear the field will also return `true`.

Does someone know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an incorrect assumption being made here:

```js
this.$emit("input", newValue);
this.formatBasedRules = this.getValidationRules(newValue);
```

and then inside `getValidationRules`:

```js
const result = rule(this.value);
```

Emitting the `input` event will immediately update the data within the parent component but the child won't be updated with that data until the next round of rendering occurs. Rendering doesn't happen immediately, it's batched up at the start of the next tick. The new value for `value` prop won't be passed to the child until that rendering occurs. As a result `this.value` will still be the old value at the point it is accessed in `getValidationRules`.

I would be inclined to write `formatBasedRules` as a computed property instead so it is always in sync with `value`. A flag may be required to prevent it showing the error until after an initial attempt at user input.

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons `getValidation` only runs with old value.
If we change to `maskItem.value`, it works

```
 getValidation: function(maskItem) {
      return maskItem.validation.map(rule => value => {
        const newValue = maskItem.value
        return (newValue && rule.pattern.test(newValue)) || rule.message;
      });
    },
```

Check [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/menu-picker-validation-9lij4)